# Banner not visible MDTopAppBar (toolbar)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I don’t understand why the color, text, navigation bar icon on the first stage is not visible, if two navigations are combined together. And on the second stage, it is visible, but somehow in the background, that is, if you add a label widget with text at the top, it will lie directly on the banner.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>

    MDList:

        OneLineListItem:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

        OneLineListItem:
            text: "Screen 2"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"

MDScreen:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    
    MDTopAppBar:
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 4
        title: "FID: Find Image Description"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        
    MDNavigationLayout:
        
        MDScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 1"

                MDBottomNavigation:
                    #panel_color: "#eeeaea"
                    selected_color_background: "orange"
                    text_color_active: "lightgrey"
                
                    MDBottomNavigationItem:
                        name: 'screen 1'
                        text: 'Load'
                        icon: 'gmail'
                
                    MDBottomNavigationItem:
                        id: mybtn
                        name: 'screen 2'
                        text: 'Image'
                        icon: 'twitter'
                
                    MDBottomNavigationItem:
                        name: 'screen 3'
                        text: 'Text'
                        icon: 'linkedin'

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 2"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''

class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDScrollView):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```